Algorithm Optimization - Lights' Out game modification
I am given a m x n board (maximum 8), and k pieces (maximum 15), and a depth variable (maximum 4). The board contains values between 0 and depth. When you put a piece on the board, it will increment the board according to where the  "X" in  the piece overlap with the board cell. When the value of a cell is depth - 1, it becomes 0.
For example, if depth = 2 and board is
001
011
011

When we put a piece with the shape of
.X
XX

at position (1,0) it will become:
001
001
101

The goal is to output the coordinates of the pieces that will zero out the board completely.
I have try the following backtracking attempt, with memoization and pruning:
 private boolean isValidPartialSolution(Board board) { // pruning
        char[][] currentGrid = board.getGrid();
        int depth = board.getDepth();

        for (char[] row : currentGrid) {
            for (char cell : row) {
                if (cell != '0' && Character.getNumericValue(cell) >= depth) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

private boolean backtrack(Board board, Piece[] pieces, int index) {
        if (index == pieces.length) {
            return this.isValid();
        }
        if (!isValidPartialSolution(board)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid partial solution");
            return false;
        }
        String key = generateKey(board, pieces, index);
        if (memoization.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println("Key exists");
            return memoization.get(key); // Return memoized result
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < board.getGrid().length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.getGrid()[0].length; col++) {
                if (board.canPlace(pieces[index], row, col)) {
                    board.placePiece(pieces[index], row, col, depth);
                    if (backtrack(board, pieces, index + 1)) {
                        memoization.put(key, true);
                        return true;
                    }
                    board.removePiece(pieces[index], row, col, depth);
                }
            }
        }
        memoization.put(key, false);
        return false;
    }

but the code is still very slow for larger inputs. I would appreciate any help to optimize this algorithm.

Maybe you need a better algorithm. This looks like a candidate for meet-in-the-middle to me.

What do you mean by meet-in-the-middle? Brute-forcing?

No, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack. It uses Birthday Paradox.

Actually, this is a better description of what I meant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack

You have any thoughts on how to improve my algorithm?
